# http.get() does not add my parameters in headers

Tags: dart, flutter, http-get, url-parameters

I'm trying to access an API using flutter and I've been having issues with it. I added a map to the `http.get(headers: myParameters)` and the server still does not process my request, so i printed my `.headers` and the map i added was not part of the headers

```
    var params = {"key": "apiKey"};
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://api.testapp.com/v1");
    var response = await http.get(uri, headers: params); 
    print(response.headers);
```

After i printed it, i got a json map but my parameters weren't listed with it, are they no being added when the request is sent?

```
{via: 1.1 vegur, content-type: application/json, connection: keep-alive, date: Fri, 05 Apr 2019 10:14:49 GMT, content-length: 92, server: gunicorn/19.9.0}
```

Comment: Is there a `response.request.headers`? Print this instead. You are printing the headers of the response you get from the server, not the headers from the request you send.

Comment: Are you sure that the key is meant to be sent as an HTTP header, rather than in the URL query string or POST form or body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [HttpHeaders](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/HttpHeaders-class.html):

```
var params = {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Basic your_api_token_here"};
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://api.testapp.com/v1");
var response = await http.get(uri, headers: params); 
print(response.headers);
```